# has_and_belongs_to_many or has_many :through or something else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am in a situation to come up with good model design for the following scenario
There is a `User` model which has one `Profile`.Also `Category` is a different model. Each `Profile` likes and dislikes some `Categories`. So how to create the migrations and models. Also I am forced to use [multiselect](http://loudev.com/) to select the likes and dislikes when ever a profile is created or edited.

What I have planned is to create a model say `Like` which is related to `Profile` in the following way.

```
Profile  -> has_one :like 

Like     -> has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
            belongs_to: profile

Category -> has_and_belongs_to_many :likes
```

Likewise for dislikes too. So that when we get `@profile.like.categories` all the categories liked by the specific `@profile` will be listed.

Is what I have in mind advisable. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

HABTM is what I'd recommend for this too -- its main feature is to provide a way for `likes` to have many`categories` -- if you don't need any extra attributes, you'll be okay with HABTM

Personally, I would refactor to remove the `Like` model, and just give a `Profile` HABTM `categories`:

```
#app/models/profile.rb
Class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, join_table: "likes_profiles", foreign_key: "like_id"
end

#app/models/category.rb
Class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, join_table: "likes_profiles", association_foreign_key: "like_id"
end
```

This treats every `category` as a `like` in the relationship. I appreciate it's not able to handle `dislikes`, but it will hopefully give you some ideas as to what you can do